# Modify default navigation bar or create fully custom navigation bar from UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I worked on app, and I cannot choose what to do: 1) Modify default UINavigationBar or 2) Create my own view as navigation bar and use it 3) Or even more - just place need elements (buttons, imageViews and label) on view. What is the best option? And what advantages when use default navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your question may vary depending how custom is your design.

If UI is pretty close to native, then just use `UINavigationBar.appearance()` to modify font, font color, etc.
If UI is too complex, then I still recommend to not waste your time, but try to find existing solution from source like [awesome-ios](https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios).
Main advantage of using default navigation bar - is to deliver UI with what users are familiar already. And it also be consistent with many other mobile applications.